# com object creation in edge and chrome-autohotkey

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey, comobject

We have a tool where autohotkey is used and the tool is designed to work for Internet explorer.
As you know now Internet explorer is no more used, we have to switch the code to work with other browsers. We have used comobject for Internet explorer:

```
'ie := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")`
`ie.Visible := true'
```

I have seen in some forums that comobject is not supported for Edge and Chrome.
Can you suggest the alternate for above code?

TIA.

Comment: See this. [chrome.commands](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/commands/)

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?